# Looking for some library to extract HTML pages from CHM files

Tags: chm

Just like in subject. I'm looking for a library for any scripting language (preferable: php, ruby, python, perl) that allow me to extract HTML source files from CHM package.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Dropped tags for each language, as it's a language-agnostic (mostly) question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on CPAN found [Archive::Chm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Chm) and [Text::CHM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CHM).

Comment: yeah found that earlier but unfortunately i got some problems compiling this modules (OS X Leopard + MacPorts)